# Cant move content to center

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'am trying to center this:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Here is the HTML:

```
<section class="page-section parallax directions" id="location" style="padding-top:10%">
    <div class="container div-table">
    <div class="parallax-bg" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5" data-stellar-vertical-offset="-150"></div>
    <div class="parallax-overlay"></div>
    <div class="parallax-inner text-center">
        <?php
            session_start();
            if(isset($_SESSION['playername']))
            {
            ?>
        <div class="panel panel-warning" style="padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px">
            <h3 class='panel-header panel shadow text-center'><?php echo $_SESSION['playername'] ?> UCP</h3>
            <div class="panel panel-body">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="text-center">
                            <h4><a href="signature.php?user=<?php echo $_SESSION['playername'] ?>">My Signature</a></h4>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="text-center">
                            <h4><a href="profile.php?user=<?php echo $_SESSION['playername'] ?>">My Profile</a></h4>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="text-center">
                            <h4><a href="account/change.php">Change My Password</a></h4>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="text-center">
                            <h4><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></h4>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
            }
            else
            {
                header("location:index.php");
            }
            ?>
    </div>
</section>
```

I'm using bootstrap btw if is thats the matter.

EDIT: i have edited the code above completely which i hasnt shown fully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `margin:auto` on your table

```css
.centerTable {
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="page-section parallax directions" id="location" style="padding-top:10%">
    <div class="container div-table">
        <div class="parallax-bg" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5" data-stellar-vertical-offset="-150"></div>
        <div class="parallax-overlay"></div>
        <div class="parallax-inner text-center">

            <div class="panel panel-warning" style="padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px">
                <h3 class='panel-header panel shadow text-center'>UCP</h3>
                <div class="panel panel-body">
                    <table class="centerTable">
                        <tr><td class="text-center"><h4><a href="">My Signature</a></h4></td></tr>
                        <tr><td class="text-center"><h4><a href="">My Profile</a></h4></td></tr>
                        <tr><td class="text-center"><h4><a href="">Change My Password</a></h4></td></tr>
                        <tr><td class="text-center"><h4><a href="">Logout</a></h4></td></tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>


        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Why can't use bootstrap's 'table' class instead of .centerTable class?

Comment: didnt worked for me

Answer (score 1):

try padding-left:auto; and padding-right:auto; instead, 10px is not a lot

Regards

Rachel

Comment: if you want to use %, use 40% and allow your div 20% width

Answer (score 1):

How about some simple CSS...

```
<div class="panel panel-body" style="width:150px;margin:auto;border:1px solid black;">
```

I put the border on so you could see it better to adjust the width as you need. You can use a percentage in the width also.

Answer (score 1):

create an id for your table, something like `mytable` and style it like so:

```
#mytable {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Here's the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/99x50s2s/102/).

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/99x50s2s/100/

Use the bootstrap's "text-center" class and also add "table" class to the HTML table.

```
<div class="panel panel-warning" style="padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px">
    <h3 class='panel-header panel shadow text-center'><?php echo $_SESSION['playername'] ?> UCP</h3>
    <div class="panel panel-body">
        <table class="table">
            <tr><td class="text-center"><h4><a href="signature.php?user=<?php echo $_SESSION['playername'] ?>">My Signature</a></h4></td></tr>
            <tr><td class="text-center"><h4><a href="profile.php?user=<?php echo $_SESSION['playername'] ?>">My Profile</a></h4></td></tr>
            <tr><td class="text-center"><h4><a href="account/change.php">Change My Password</a></h4></td></tr>
            <tr><td class="text-center"><h4><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></h4></td></tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```